# How to change a JTextField based on a JComboBox selection

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, jcombobox, itemlistener

This is just a silly program I am working on for school but I am having some trouble. I have a JComboBox and based on what the user selects I want to change the text field. I'm having some trouble with that however, as it stands now the program compiles and runs but the text field doesn't change. I've found plenty of examples of people doing far more complicated things but I just need a simple solution. Here is the code. Thanks!

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class emocon extends JFrame implements ItemListener {
JPanel row1 = new JPanel();
JComboBox choose = new JComboBox();
JPanel row2 = new JPanel();
JTextField text = new JTextField(10);
//image will be displayed here
JPanel row3 = new JPanel();
JLabel pic = new JLabel();

//Images
ImageIcon happy = new ImageIcon("images/happy.gif");
ImageIcon lol = new ImageIcon("images/lol.gif");
ImageIcon winky = new ImageIcon("images/winky.gif");
ImageIcon sad = new ImageIcon("images/sad.gif");
ImageIcon worried = new ImageIcon("images/worried.gif");
ImageIcon angry = new ImageIcon("images/angry.gif");
ImageIcon shock = new ImageIcon("images/shock.gif");
ImageIcon uninpressed = new ImageIcon("images/uninpressed.gif");
ImageIcon yawn = new ImageIcon("images/yawn.gif");
ImageIcon evil = new ImageIcon("images/evil.gif");

public emocon(){
    setTitle("Emoticon Converter");
    setSize(350,350);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);

GridLayout two = new GridLayout(3,1);
setLayout(two);
 choose.addItem("Happy");
 choose.addItem("LOL");
 choose.addItem("Winky");
 choose.addItem("Sad");
 choose.addItem("Worried");
 choose.addItem("Angry");
 choose.addItem("Shock");
 choose.addItem("Uninpressed");
 choose.addItem("Yawn");
 choose.addItem("Evil");
choose.addItemListener(this);
row1.add(choose);
row2.add(text);
row3.add(pic); 
add(row1);
add(row2);
add(row3);

}
@Override
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent item) {
Object source = item.getSource();
String emo = source.toString();
if (emo == "Sad"){
    text.setText("hjgjhg");
}
}   
public static void main(String[] args) {
    emocon emo = new emocon();
}
}
```

Comment: 1) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow. 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've a problem here:

```
if (emo == "Sad"){
    text.setText("hjgjhg");
}
```

Don't compare Strings using `==`. Use the `equals(...)` or the `equalsIgnoreCase(...)` method instead. Understand that == checks if the two *objects* are the same which is not what you're interested in. The methods on the other hand check if the two Strings have the same characters in the same order, and that's what matters here.  So instead of

```
if (fu == "bar") {
  // do something
}
```

do,

```
if ("bar".equals(fu)) {
  // do something
}
```

or,

```
if ("bar".equalsIgnoreCase(fu)) {
  // do something
}
```

---

EDIT

Your other problem is that you're just getting the source from the ItemEvent. The source is the **JComboBox**, not what you want. You need to get the selected item!

Try using a different method available in your ItemEvent object, not `getSource()`.

Comment: Thank you for your help is was something I did not know. Unfortunately it still didn't change the text box. Any other tips? thanks!

Comment: @Rostro: see edit. You should do some debugging for this like printing emo via println(...) to see what it actually is.

Comment: I'm trying some different different methods found here:http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/ItemEvent.html . I printed out emo and I got the string for each item in the combobox. I believe this is what I want so I'm not sure why it wont work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Get the selected item like this:

```
String item = (String)jComboBox.getSelectedItem();
if(item.equals("Sad")){
    text.setText("hjgjhg");
}
```

Comment: thank you for you help. On a side note, line 2 is missing a closing parentheses. When I run the program I get this error " non-static method getSelectedItem() cannot be referenced from a static context" Thanks!

Comment: @Rostro, the error is pretty clear, use the code in a non static method, your jcombobox is not static.

Comment: @Rostro: You don't need to do this. Again just use the ItemEvent's `getItem()` method as I told you previously. It's all in the ItemEvent.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels that worked after I played with it a bit. Thanks for the help both of you!